# How to remove a file in iPhone SDK that I can't easily see

Tags: iphone

I think I removed my icon.png the wrong way, and it's still in the project somewhere. I try to upload a new icon.png and it won't let me giving me an error that it can't do it. Then I upload 'con.png' and try to rename it to 'icon.png' and it won't let me do that. So I'm thinking I must have deleted the original icon.png the wrong way (selected 'delete references' instead of 'also move to trash'). Is there a way to find this file so I can quickly remove it and get back to uploading my new icon.png?

Comment: Have you checked your project directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project file icon under "groups and files" in the project window and pick "open with finder". Search that directory for your file and delete it. Use the search box in the upper right of the project window if you want to make sure there's not still a reference to Icon.png somewhere in the project.